# Handling errors in Ajax return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to show errors when Ajax is not success but I can't get deep into results to show the exact error.

## sample

here is what I get in network tab `playground`

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"title":["The title field is required."],"slug":["The slug field is required."]}}
```

and `JSON`

```
message The given data was invalid.
errors  {…}
title   […]
0   The title field is required.
slug    […]
0   The slug field is required.
```

`Console`

```
message
The given data was invalid.
errors
{…}
slug: Array [ "The slug field is required." ]
title: Array [ "The title field is required." ]
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

What I can get in my view is this:

```
message - The given data was invalid.
errors - [object Object]
```

## Code

```
error:function(data){
    if( data.status === 422 ) {
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
        $.each( errors , function( key, value ) {
            console.log(key);
            console.log(value);
            errorsHtml += '<li><b>' + key + '</b> - ' + value + '</li>';
        });
        errorsHtml += '</ul></div>';
        $( '#form-errors' ).html( errorsHtml );
    } else if( data.status === 500 ){
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        $( '#form-errors' ).append(errors.message);
    } else {
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        $( '#form-errors' ).append(errors.message);
    }
}
```

#### What I want

I want to get `key` and `value` from `errors` part.

#### Issue

Based on my code above if I loop my `value` for second time like:

```
//basic
$.each( errors , function( key, value ) {
  //second time loop to get into errors
  $.each( value , function( df, er ) {
    console.log(df);
    console.log(er);
  });
  errorsHtml += '<li><b>' + key + '</b> - ' + value + '</li>';
});
```

this doesn't work.

## Question

How can I get my errors part and return those `key` & `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `errors` variable that you're assigning from `data.responseJSON` contains the value you're seeing in the playground.

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"title":["The title field is required."],"slug":["The slug field is required."]}}
```

You can traverse this object and directly access the `errors` property of the object. See where I use `$.each(errors.errors, //...` below to access the property directly. With some assumptions on my part, you should be able to do the following:

```js
// mocking the data object for this example
var data = {responseJSON: {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"title":["The title field is required."],"slug":["The slug field is required."]}}};

var errors = data.responseJSON;
errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';

$.each(errors.errors , function( key, value ) {
    errorsHtml += '<li><b>' + key + '</b> - ' + value[0] + '</li>';
});

errorsHtml += '</ul></div>';
$('#form-errors').html(errorsHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="form-errors"></div>
```